# Why are we allowed to use different zone schemes in reciprocal lattice (Explain with intution)

Tags: condensed-matter

So I have been learning condensed matter at university and there is one central theme that is bugging me, the idea of reduced and periodic zone schemes in the reciprocal lattice. I understand the extended as that seems fairly obvious. But then in reduced/periodic we have this idea that if a particle leaves the 1st Brillouin zone it reappears on the other side. So physically this is saying if you keep increasing k it will suddenly decrease. Or since k = 2*pi/wavelength, the same can be said for wavelength.

Cam someone explain how to go about thinking about this?

I keep hearing that k maps to other ks but that doesn't help.

Please don't give a mathmatical description using bloch's theorem, a little maths is okay as long as it's intuitive in something outside of condensed matter.

Comment: If you are going to ignore Bloch’s theorem, then it is hopeless. The main problem here is you need to adjust your intuition to match Bloch’s. Intuition is a notable fickle and personal thing to rely on.

Comment: Some intuition can be provided with the aid of Fourier transform concepts (not math). Would that do?

Answer (score 1):

Some intuition as to why: ***"k maps to other ks"***. This stems from your interest in function values at ***grid points*** only.

For simplicity, assume a one dimensional space domain and ignore complex numbers. Suppose your state function is $sin(kx)$ and your grid points are $x_n=na$ for ***n=0,1,2,...***. Here, ***a*** is the grid's interval.

Now gradually decrease the wavelength of $sin(kx)$. Grid point values will gradually change. But once the wavelength is small enough so that ***one full wavelength*** is added between the grid points, grid points values are again the same as in $sin(kx)$. This can easily be seen mathematically: $sin(kx_n)=sin( [k+\frac{2\pi}{a}]*x_n)$.

So from the point of view of the  grid-points, $[k+\frac{2\pi}{a}]$ can be ***reduced*** to $k$. More generally, any $k$ above $\frac{2\pi}{a}$ can be reduced to ***k*** in the ***zone*** of $[0,\frac{2\pi}{a}]$.